# Rails repopulate view after destroy. Whenever

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, cron, whenever

I've setup a "Whenever" task that truncates a "news" table, refreshes my sitemap, then repopulates the news table.  All at 5am everyday. (This gets rid of old news items and fetches new ones using nokogiri.)

The problem is, every morning, i wake up and my news view is empty and I have to repopulate it manually...

This is the whenever task:

```
every 1.day, :at => '5:00 am' do
  runner "News.destroy_all"
  rake "-s sitemap:refresh"
  rake "rss:fetch"
end
```

Should I just make the fetch at 5:01 instead? or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the table is emptied, the problem lies in one of both `rake` tasks. My guess is that you should remove the `-s` (silent) flag.

If I'm interpreting the [whenever docs](https://github.com/javan/whenever#define-your-own-job-types) correct, a `rake` jobtype is defined as:

```
job_type :rake, "cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output"
```

So the output is already silenced.

Then again, there might be some other error in on of your tasks.

Comment: Not a chance! I've tested the hell out of these tasks. Individually they all absolutely work. I removed the "silent" from them though. So we'll see what it looks like tomorrow morning. I'll get back to you.

Comment: 10 o'clock and all is well!